# Storing filenames of multiple uploaded files into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Okay I get to this and at this momento I'm printing only the 1st imagem that is submited! How can I do to be unlimiteed so my foreach can ***INSERT*** all of them ?

```
 <table width="400">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<p>Pictures:
<input type="file" name="pictures[]"  />
<input type="file" name="pictures[]"  />

<input type="submit" value="Send" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Rs_maxID    ['MAX(projectos_ID)']; ?>" name="idz" id="idz" />
</p>
</form>

<?php
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/$name");
    }
}
foreach($_FILES as $file)
    {

            #upload deu certo
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO projectoimagens (projecto_fk, image)
                                  VALUES (, '".$_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]."')");
        }


?>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question....

Comment: I want to print into my database the directory of the pictures

Comment: But what do you mean 'print' into your 'database the directory of the pictures'? You mean, you want to store the image data or the image name in the database? Please elaborate.

Comment: the image name ! the data is already being uploaded to a directory!and i just need to print "uploads/$name" in the database !

Comment: Is it print == INSERT? Btw, are you doing some file check there, are you?

Comment: look at the new description :)

Answer (score 4):

Your question is worded very awkward. Not sure if this is what you are after:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or trigger_error('Unable to connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('database_name') or trigger_error('Unable to select DB: ' . mysql_error());

foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/$name");
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('something', 'somethingelse', 'uploads/" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "');") or trigger_error('Unable to INsert: ' . mysql_error()); 
    }
}
?>
```

That might be what you are looking for. You will have to modify it extensively to match your database information, but hopefully that gets you to where you are wanting to go.

Comment: not working actualy :( parse error on mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('something', 'somethingelse', 'uploads/" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "');") or trigger_error('Unable to INsert: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: col1, col2, col3 exist in your database table? What's the error?

Comment: diogo, if there is a parser error, please post the error not the code it throws an error on. As far as I can see the syntax is correct, granted, I had to edit it ~ 10 minutes ago due to a missing ' on the first line. But as stated, you will need to modify the data to match your own database. This will not work right off the bat.